# Metric spaces whose open sets form a $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

I have the following question

> Characterise the metric spaces whose open sets form a $\sigma$-algebra.

I apologise if this seems like too basic of a question to ask here, but seeing as English is not my native language, I am having some trouble understanding exactly what is expected of me in this question. Can anyone please assist in giving me some clarity?

Comment: "Characterize" means to find a simple description of the things in question. So you're being asked to find a _simpler_ property that holds for a metric space if and only if its open sets constitue a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @HenningMakholm As you said, "characterize" is to find a simple description of the things in question. In this case, to find a simple description of "the metric spaces whose open sets form a $\sigma$-algebra". In principle, it does not have be simpler or more difficult than anything.

Comment: @user27454: It wouldn't be much of an exercise it you could answer it just by saying "those metric spaces whose open sets form a $\sigma$-algebra". Assuming that the question is not a troll question, we need to interpret it as asking for a simpler description than the one in the question itself.

Comment: @HenningMakholm OK, now I understand what you were trying to say.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: the $\sigma$-algebra also contains all the closed sets.  What does it say about the metric space if every one-point set $\{x\}$ is open?

Comment: If every singeton set $\{x \}$ is open, is it not the discrete metric?

Comment: @Robert Why the singletons are in the $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @user27454 As Robert writes ... they are closed (and therefore complements of open sets) ...

Comment: @user27454 A singleton set in a metric space is necessarily closed.

Comment: Alternatively $\{x\}=\bigcap\limits_{n\in \mathbb N}B_{1/n}(x)$, and a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable intersections.

Comment: So, we have a characterization!

Comment: @user229672: It does not have to be _the_ discrete metric (defined by $d(x,y)=1$ whenever $x\ne y$) -- it is enough that every point is isolated.

Comment: @DaríoG In summary and to conclude, what is the characterization formally?

Comment: @hmakholmleftoverMonica If each point is isolated, then every set is open. This is called the discrete topology.

Comment: @Curious In a metric space (X,d) the collection of open sets forms a $\sigma$-algebra if and only if (X,d) is a discrete metric space if and only if $\{x\}$ es abierto para todo $x\in X$.